# Error in the code,when running in visual studio 2017 and not in codeblocks

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

struct student {
    std::string name;

    int age;

   float marks;

};

student initiateStudent(std::string name, int age, float marks)
{
    student s;
    s.age = age;
    s.marks = marks;
    s.name = name;
    return s;

}
student* highestScore(student** stud, int total)
{
    float temp = (*stud)->marks;
    student **counter= new (student*);

    *counter = *stud;
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
       // std::cout<<(*stud)->marks;
        if (temp < (*stud)->marks)
        {
            *counter = *stud;
            temp = (*stud)->marks;
        }
        (*stud)++;
    }
    *stud = *counter;
    delete counter;
    return *stud;
}
int main()
{
        int totalStudents = 1;

        std::string name;

        int age;

        float marks;

        std::cin >> totalStudents;

        student *stud = new student[totalStudents];

        for (int i = 0; i < totalStudents; i++) {
            std::cout << "\nEnter Name: ";
            std::cin >> name;
            std::cout << "\nEnter age: ";
            std::cin >> age;
            std::cout << "\nEnter Marks: ";
            std::cin >> marks;

            stud[i] = initiateStudent(name, age, marks);
            //std::cout << "\n Name: " << stud[i].name << "\n" << stud[i].marks;

        }

        student *topper = highestScore(&stud, totalStudents);

        //std::cout << "\nPrinting in Main : " << topper->name;
        std::cout<<std::endl << topper->name << " is the topper with " << topper->marks << " marks" << std::endl;


        delete[] stud;
        std::cin.get();

        return 0;
    }
```

here is the error that pops up when i am done entering values for all the students:
[Visual studio error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1TT6.png)

but when i run the same code in code::blocks, it runs smooth and displays the ouput:

[same code on codeblocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAyLO.png)

but even the codeblock window shows an error, idk what is the problem, any help will be great.

Comment: Post error messages (and example input /output) as block-formatted text (like code), not just image.

Comment: Among other things, something stylistic that baffles me especially is why you think you need to dynamically allocate a single pointer, when it could simply be on the stack... and why, if it exists to find the student with the highest mark, it's called `counter`. And there are some more points: why not just use `std::vector` instead of the other `new`? and `std::max_element()`? and iterators instead of raw pointers? It's odd to tag this as `c++11` and yet make so little effort to use the great Standard Library features included in that version, instead reinvent them, in far more dangerous ways.

Comment: Is there a reason you're creating an array of pointers? `struct` objects don't need to be pointers.

Comment: @cybermonkey The program shown does not, in fact, create an array of pointers. The only array being created, in `new student[totalStudents]`, is an array of `student` structures.

Answer (score 1):

`highestScore` has the side effect of modifying `stud` in `main`, so that it no longer points to a block allocated with `new`, but somewhere in the middle of that block. Then `delete[] stud` exhibits undefined behavior.

Have `highestScore` take `student*`, and remove extra levels of indirection everywhere inside. Better still, use `std::vector<student>` throughout, and avoid manual memory management.